# Get included file real path

Tags: php, file, path, include

I have a project with the following structure:

```
.credentials
helpers.php
home.php
admin\
   login.php
   register.php
```

In the `helpers.php`, i'm trying to get the content of `.credentials` by doing `file_get_contents('.credentials')`, but this works only if the then i include that file in file in the same directory (for example `home.php`), but when I try to do something like:

```
include('../helpers.php');
```

in the `admin/login.php` file, it no longer works, because `helpers.php` tries to find `admin/.credentials`

How can i avoid this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use absolute pathes for includes.

Use the constant `__DIR__` to refer to the (real!) directory of the current PHP file.

Example (from home.php):

```
include __DIR__ . '/admin/login.php';
```

Comment: yup, but how would i require the `helpers` from the `login.php` file?

Comment: `include __DIR__ .'/../helpers.php'; `

Comment: Surely that is a relative path? Relative to `__DIR__`